# Uncaught (in promise) Error when using PDF.js viewer with React.js library?

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js

I installed [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) and tried to import it and use it with `react` using the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {

    pdfjs.getDocument('./sample.pdf').promise.then(doc => console.log(doc.numPages))
  }

  render() {
    return <div>test pdf</div>
  }
}

export default App
```

but I'm getting the next error at console

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot read property 'WorkerMessageHandler' of undefined".
```

I tried also to change the import statement to :

`import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'`

but I got this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to import `pdfjs` with `require` based on this discussion [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10317) and this example [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js)

Comment: I also tried to replace import with `const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist')` but the same first error appears

Comment: Since you are using react, maybe try this react-based library for pdfjs, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-js

Comment: It looks something different. I would like to use the same Mozilla one.